# Extract rows from dataframe based on values in list

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
split_df = 
     filename  width  height  class  xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax
0  128778.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  4489   818  4915  1417
1  128778.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  3023  1278  3403  1854
2  128776.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  3369  1310  3759  1890
3  128776.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  3721  1339  4116  1919
4  128775.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  4076  1368  4476  1952
```

And then two lists, train_set and test_set, these are two lists like so:

```
train_set = ["128778.JPG", "128776.JPG"]
test_set = ["128775.JPG"]
```

So basically I was wondering if there's a way to split the dataframe based on these two lists kinda like this:

```
> train_df = split(split_df, train_set)
> train_df 
>        filename  width  height  class  xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax
    0  128778.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  4489   818  4915  1417
    1  128778.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  3023  1278  3403  1854
    2  128776.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  3369  1310  3759  1890
    3  128776.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  3721  1339  4116  1919
> test_df = split(split_df, test_set)
> test_df 

>         filename  width  height  class  xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax
    0   128775.JPG   5472    3648  Panel  4076  1368  4476  1952
```

Comment: Check with isin

Comment: Yep, since your hypothetical `split` function is called each time, saving no computation, this is nothing but a basic filter.

Comment: @W-B not even `isin`. `just filename==x`

Comment: I haven't really worked a lot with pandas, I just used split as a stand-in for some built in method.

Comment: @roganjosh train_set  need isin right ?

Comment: @W-B `!= "128775.JPG"` would do in this case. I suspect it's faster than `isin`? The OP intends to do the separation in 2 parts already. There's a chronic lack of effort here.

Comment: @roganjosh this is base on the assumption there are no other corrupt lines in the original dataframe other than above three filenames

Comment: @W-B fair point, I guess `isin` is more resilient there